# Change JSON received units data from Forecast api service

Tags: java, json, api

I want change JSON received data from Forecast api to custom units. In API's doc they're wrote i should change query parameters to get this done.

the API call look like this:

> https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE

i wonder how i could send option for changing units. this is what they're wrote:

> Options
>   The API request may optionally be modified through the use of query parameters. It will respond to the following:
>   units=[setting]: Return the API response in units other than the default Imperial units.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the api states that optional parameters can be added as query parameters to the url , your url should look like

> https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE?units=VALUE

VALUE is the the type of unit you want to select
Some options are

- us
- si
- ca
- uk2
- auto